# Rotate vector of points by point coordinate

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

Is there a simple way of shifting a set of points stored in a `cv::vector<cv::Point>` by an amount defined by a `cv::Point`? Something like std::rotate, but for only one coordinate of the point. It should take into account the size of the vector.

For example,

`[1,0],[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]` is shifted by `[0,2]` to `[1,2],[0,3],[1,0],[2,1]`

The only way I can think of is doing it manually with a for loop.

Comment: `std::rotate` does not take a custom swapper, so you'd need to design iterator adapters to provide a view of your point's y-coordinates. You're better off writing the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. create a `Mat` from `vector<Point>`. It'll be a 2 channel matrix, Nx1
2. reshape so that it becomes a 1 channel matrix, Nx2
3. get the column that contains the x and y coordinates
4. use rotate on that column using `MatIterator`

Note that `Mat` has no reverse iterator (to implement *right* rotation), so, when shift is negative, you should add the size of the `vector<Point>` to the shift and use the *left* rotation.

You're mostly playing around with matrix headers, so data won't be copied.

Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    vector<Point> pts = { Point(1, 0), Point(0, 1), Point(1, 2), Point(2, 3) };
    Point shift(0,2);

    for (const Point& p : pts) { cout << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "] "; } cout << endl;

    // [1, 0] [0, 1] [1, 2] [2, 3]

    // ----------------------------  

    Mat mpts(pts);
    Mat xy = mpts.reshape(1);
    Mat x = xy.col(0);
    Mat y = xy.col(1);

    if (shift.x < 0)
        shift.x += pts.size();

    std::rotate(x.begin<Point::value_type>(), x.begin<Point::value_type>() + shift.x, x.end<Point::value_type>());

    if (shift.y < 0)
        shift.y += pts.size();

    std::rotate(y.begin<Point::value_type>(), y.begin<Point::value_type>() + shift.y, y.end<Point::value_type>());

    // ----------------------------        

    for (const Point& p : pts) { cout << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "] "; } cout << endl;

    // [1, 2] [0, 3] [1, 0] [2, 1]

    return 0;
}
```